# Explanation of illegal multi-byte encoding leading to XSS

Tags: xss, encoding

I'm reading [this](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr36/) report on unicode security and found the following paragraphs confusing:

> When converting from a multi-byte encoding, a byte value may not be a
>   valid trailing byte, in a context where it follows a particular
>   leading byte. For example, when converting UTF-8 input, the byte
>   sequence E3 80 22 is malformed because 0x22 is not a valid second
>   trailing byte following the leading byte 0xE3. Some conversion code
>   may report the three-byte sequence E3 80 22 as one illegal sequence
>   and continue converting the rest, while other conversion code may
>   report only the two-byte sequence E3 80 as an illegal sequence and
>   continue converting with the 0x22 byte which is a syntax character in
>   HTML and XML (U+0022 double quote). Implementations that report the
>   0x22 byte as part of the illegal sequence can be exploited for
>   cross-site-scripting (XSS) attacks.
>
> Therefore, an illegal byte sequence must not include bytes that encode
>   valid characters or are leading bytes for valid characters.

Based on the example described (E3 80 22) as a byte sequence, it is clear that it not valid:

```
>>> b'\xe3\x80\x22'.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: invalid continuation byte
```

and the question is how a good parser/converter is supposed to manage this type of error.

Probably I'm misunderstanding something, but it says that some may report an error with the whole sequence (`E3 80 22`), but others may report an error with `E3 80` and continue converting the `22` byte as a double quote. However, it says that when the report includes the `22` byte, then this can be exploited in a XSS attack. That's the part that is confusing; I would have thought that it was the second instance the one leading to XSS vulnerabilities. What is the rationale to think it should be the first  instance vulnerable to XSS?

An additional question: How is this type of issue exploitable in practice (assuming we are interested in web applications)? Am I supposed to simply use URL encoding or HTML encoding (`%E3%80%22` and `&#xE3&#x80&#x22`, respectively) and hope for the best?

Answer (score 1):

If your webpage considers 'E3 80 22' as one sequence then the '22' won't be escaped... if you deliver this page to a browser who considers 'E3 80 22' as 'E3 80' + '22', stripping the illegal sequence results in '22' then you have an '22' in there you don't want and this allows XSS attacks.

Comment: Thanks, but aren't you saying that detecting E3 80 as illegal and continue parsing 22 is the one case that facilities XSS? The document says that when E3 80 22 is reported as an illegal sequence, then this can be exploited in a XSS.

Comment: No. Let's say you loop through every character in a string... e3 80 22 counts as one 'illegal' entity so you skip it. If you replace the character 22 with 32 in '22 e3 80 22'  you get '32 e3 80 22' which is '(32) (e3 80 22)' but now a DIFFERENT implementation treats this as '(32) (e3 80) (22)'. If the first implementation treated it as '(32) (e3 80) (22)' as well we'd get '(32) (e3 80) (32)' which would be safer.. worst case this gets treated as a space plus illegal (so skipped) which at least isn't an XSS but you loose the last space. I might be wrong but that's how I understand it.

Comment: Of course...  browsers should just reject illegal uft8 completely... any program should instead of trying to fix things which often just introduces other problems.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but you're adding an additional byte which is not considered in the initial example. I think you're using the same logic  explained in the question; basically, a parser that outputs (e3 80)(22) is unsafe, but according to the document, the other implementation is considered unsafe (e3 80 22).

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your example, but it would be helpful if you could explain it only with three bytes.

Comment: You have two kinds of implementation. One treats it as '(e3 80 22)' type A and one as '(e3 80) (22)'  type B. If B is folllowed by A then you're safe... A will ignore the '22'. If A is followed by B you're not safe. Since you don't know which type follows your type which strategy is safe regardless whether A or B follows? And that would be B, not A.  Using B is always safe. If you use A and feed your output to A you're fine but not when you feed it to B. If you use B you can feed it to A and it's fine and feed it to B and it's also fine.

Comment: If unicode doesn't specify how to handle this case then implementations will handle it however they want and then interactions between those is insecure. Neither A and B would be wrong but it's safer to use B in a world where A and B exist but unsafe to use A.

Comment: Okay, but notice that the referenced document doesn't assume that one implementation should be followed by another. As far as I understand, that section describes both as independent implementations. Maybe they're referring to situations in which if A detects an illegal sequence as (E3 80 3E) and removes the whole sequence, then it can be dangerous as in the example they show in other section: `<span style=width:100%✘> onMouseOver=doBadStuff()...` where ✘ is equivalent to the sequence (E3 80), and adding 3E is illegal, so deleting or replacing the three-byte sequence would be dangerous.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68594/discussion-between-robert-smith-and-mroman).